# Partial View or HtmlHelper for displaying list of items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, partial-views

I have a model that contains an `IEnumerable` of a list of custom objects.  Each item needs to be displayed with about 6 fields and an image.  So, I won't be using a grid to display the items, rather a div and styling to achieve the look I want.  With that said, I'm looking for the appropriate approach.  In the book I have, Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework by Adam Freeman and Steven Sanderson, they give an example of doing something similar in their Sports Store application, where for each item, they use this code,

```
@foreach(var p in Model.Products) {
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p);
}
```

Most other reading that I've done, and what seems to be a preferred approach to this, would be to use an `HtmlHelper` that does basically the same thing.

Which is preferred and why would I use one approach over the other?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I should have mentions that each of my items will be enclosed in it's own form and have a submit button.  This may be the reason the authors of the book I mentioned used the partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I would go the helper route if there is a **chance** that the code would be reused somewhere else.  Could it be used on another page?  Or in another project?

Something else to think about...
Helpers also help you to encapsulate view code so that you can keep your view clean and simple.  How complex is that view?  Would encapsulating some of the code assist in making the code easier to read and maintain?

Comment: I've updated my question, as I left off something pretty important. Each one of my 'items' will be encapsulated in a Form with a submit button. Think 'Add to Cart'

Comment: If it is a form then i would go the partial route.  The more complex the form the harder it would be to maintain.  It would be easier to see a syntax error or typo in the partial compared to trying to find it in a string of characters.